# How does the warping of time behave as a fourth dimension?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, differential-geometry, spacetime-dimensions

My problem is that I have a hard time grasping something if I can't conceptualize it, though maybe this can not be conceptualized, just accepted, in which case I thank you for your patience. The problem I'm facing in my mis-leading "conceptual" mind is illustrated as follows:

To describe a point on a line, we need one number. To describe a point on a curve we need two numbers. To describe a point on a "curving curve" like a helix we need three numbers (one each for the components of hight, width, and depth). If the path is traveling on a one dimensional track of time, in other words along a "line" of time, we would need a fourth number to describe its position in time. But if the path is curving through time, then there is also a horizontal component to time, so how is it will we not need 2 numbers to record a point on that arcing track?

Einstein talks of the curvature of time. Please, just explain to me how it is possible to chart a point on a curving path using one number.

Is there a way for me to understand such a process conceptually, or must I just accept it?

Again, my main desire is for this question to be answered:

If time contains curvature, and if a curving path requires at least two numbers to chart as it has a vertical component and a horizontal component, then how is time charted with one number?

Comment: Please research the difference between *extrinsic* and *intrinsic* curvature. (Eg. [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Curvature.html)) Extrinsic curvature is due to an embedding of a space into a higher dimensional space in a curved way, which is what you are imagining. The curvature dealt with in general relativity is the *intrinsic* kind: it can be defined referring only to the intrinsic properties of the 4 dimensional spacetime, without embedding it in any higher dimensional space.

Comment: @MichaelBrown. that was exactly the information I needed, thank you. So one could say that the path of an object may contain extrinsic curvature, and the plane that the path is described on may contain intrinsic curvature, but not visa-versa, correct? For example, a hyperboloid shaped plane has negative Gaussian curvature, whereas a spherical plane has positive Gaussian curvature and both are examples of intrinsic curvature, where as an object spiraling down the neck of the hyperboloid plane, or around the spherical plane is carrying extrinsic curvature, correct?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need extra numbers to chart curved geometries.  You just need a notion of distance.

For instance, to say where on Earth I am, all that is necessary is two specified numbers--my latitude and longitude.  How can I tell that I"m on a curved surface, then?  Well, if I start out at the intersection of the prime meridian and the equator, and you start out at the intersection of $10^\circ$ E and the equator, and we both agree to travel in parallel paths along our meridians, we will find that our paths cross at the north pole.  Since we both maintained our bearings, and we started on parallel paths, we conclude that the Earth is curved.

We can make a similar conclusion by measuring triangles on the surface of the Earth--if you measured the distance from New York to London, the distance from London to Cairo, and the distance from Cairo to New York, and the angles subtending these paths, you woudl find that the resulting triangle would not satisfy Heron's formula, and therefore, the triangle is inconsistent with Euclidean geometry.

Similarly, you don't need three numbers to specify your position on the helix--you just need how far you've travelled along the length of the helix to know where you are--the helix is already specified, after all.

The curvature of spacetime is much like the curvature in this sense--it doesn't obey the rules of Euclidean geometry, even though all paths are specified with just four coordinates.

Comment: Ok, so then it is not wrong to say that if those men traveling north are simultaneously being pulled in orbit around the sun, any given position taken from earths perspective will always appear "stretched" into a curve from the suns perspective and "warped" from the perspective of the galaxies center, (not saying those are extra dimensions) because the sun is experiencing time differently due to its separate motion, correct? The outer system of motion must always look into the inner and see time being stretched, correct?

Comment: @user29372: when talking about the globe analogy forget about gravity.  I'm just explaining how curvature makes paths converge.  There's no gravitational effect to travelling on the surface of the globe, it's just that it's a ball and not a box.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way I can describe this is:

**1 dimension**
If you're on a main street and are talking with your friend on the phone, telling them where on that street you are. There are only 2 directions to decide from at any moment, up or down the street.

**2 dimensions**
You're in a city, talking to your friend where to meet you. They are on a different street and need 2 coordinates to find you. At any moment they can choose to go forwards, backwards, left, right or any combination of those 4.

**3 dimensions**
You are on a specific floor of a building with a friend on a different street. You need 3 coordinates to tell them where you are, 2 to find the street and where on that street and 1 to tell them which floor you're on.

**4 dimensions**
The 4th dimension isn't space as the other ones were, this is where we have the concept of "space-time". You aren't talking with your friend on the phone, you have already arranged this meeting. For an arrangement you need 4 coordinates: what street you will meat on, where on said street, which floor of the building and what time.

This is very simple when you're looking at it in terms of simple coordinates, but then you can get curvature. Imagine a map of a hilled landscape, and trying to make your way from 1 place to another. On the flat map, it's simply a straight line. Unlike the map reality is curved, there are hills, as you walk you might find that in order to get to the other location you walk more in one direction than you would expect to on a flat surface, you have to turn to correct for the curvature of the hill. By the time you get to the second location you may have walked a significant distance turning right where the map would have pointed straight. Much like this space-time can be curved, so as you move near planets where the curvature is significant you will have moved a different "distance" through time than you would have expected.